how does the find_blobs() function from GearsBot work?
I am trying to build code that use camera to detect yellow blobs in python and GearsBot website (github repo).
first I found the lower and upper HSV for the image using python code I got this.
Lower HSV: (50.30769230769232, 42.647058823529406%, 26.27450980392157%)
Upper HSV: (67.27272727272728, 77.77777777777779%, 89.41176470588236%)

Then
I called the function find_blobs() to detect the yellow blobs
# Find blobs
blobs = camera_sensor_in6.find_blobs((52, 67, 42, 77, 26, 89), 10)

print(f"Blobs detected: {len(blobs)}")

But I got the result 0 which means there is no blobs. I tried a lot of numbers
But nothing works?
what are spoused the parameters of the find_blobs?
am I calling it wrong?

It would help to save a frame and analyze the HSV values, making sure it still matches your prior analysis results. (Separately, the question in your title is much broader than the actual question you're asking).

documentation: https://github.com/QuirkyCort/gears/wiki/Camera-Sensor and tutorials: https://github.com/QuirkyCort/gears/wiki/Tutorials (search function on the github repo)

Thanks for the website, but this website does not tell us which scale do they use for Min, and Max H values, I have tried a lot but all of them failed only black value works.

I solved the problem with this
    # Capture image before finding blobs
    camera_sensor_in6.capture_image()

